# Laravel:how to update a "hasMany" related Model?

Tags: php, web, laravel

this is my code:

```
<?php namespace Models;

class CardBizSetting extends BaseModel {

  protected $table = 'mp_member_biz_setting';
  public $timestamps = false;
  public static $unguarded = true;


  public function wechatUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany('Models\WcMemberUser', 'bizid');
  }

  public function exchangesHistories() {
    return $this->hasMany('Models\WcMemberCashHistory', 'exchange_bizid');
    // ->where('exchange_wechat_id',$this->wc_openid);
  }

  public function chargeHistories() {
    return $this->hasMany('Models\WcMemberCharge', 'charge_bizid');
    // ->where('charge_wechatid',$this->wc_openid);
  }

  // And this function doesn't work--->
  public static function updateWechatUserStatus($bizid, $wechatopenid, $status) {
    $user = self::find($bizid)->wechatUsers()->where('wc_openid', $wechatopenid)->first();
    if ($user) {
      $user->update(array('wc_ustatus' => $status));
    }
  }
}
```

and this function does not work

```
Models\CardBizSetting::updateWechatUserStatus(1,'www',1);
```

So, my question is how to update a hasMany related child model?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any error in the method `updateWechatUserStatus`. Have you checked if the scope `wechatUsers` returns what you expect ? Try to debug your code, and you will see where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I will update my issue tomorrow，and invite you to ask ，thank you